# How to use Mod Rewrite to access non-document-root folder files?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, documentroot

I have the following structure for my website codes at `/var/www/html`

```
-- files
---- test.txt

-- app
---- SomePhpCodes.php
---- SomePhpCodes.php

-- public
---- index.php
---- .htaccess
```

The document root is set to be "/var/www/html/public" but I also want to have files accessible via path "http://mywebsite/files/test.txt".

I think this must be possible using mod_rewrite in the `.htaccess` file inside `public` but I am struggling to do so.

I tried to add a rule to the default `.htaccess` that is provided by the Laravel framework. The current `.htaccess` looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # The following rule is added by me
    RewriteRule files/(.*\.txt) /var/www/html/files/$1 [L]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The current result is `Internal Server Error` when trying to access "http://mywebsite/files/test.txt". I have a feeling I might have missed some settings to make the "files" folder public but I don't have any idea how to do so.

I am stuck and if anyone can help me I will appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a symlink

```
ln -s /var/www/html/files /var/www/html/public/files
```

You will need `Options +FollowSymLinks` for this to work. Please note that this option adds a security risk as it allows accessing files outside of `DocumentRoot`.

Alternatively you can add `Alias /files /var/www/html/files` to your `VirtualHost` configuration for this site. It is a more secure option but you can't do it with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @AlexD's answer...

> think this must be possible using mod_rewrite in the `.htaccess` file

This IS possible using mod_rewrite, but not in `.htaccess`. You would need to do this directly in the main server config (or VirtualHost container).

In a *directory* (or `.htaccess`) context you are restricted to rewriting to a URL-path only. However, in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context you can rewrite to a URL-path *or* an absolute filesystem path.

However, this is not the cause of your `Internal Server Error`...

> ```
> RewriteRule files/(.*\.txt) /var/www/html/files/$1 [L]
> ```

This is most probably resulting in a rewrite-loop (hence 500 Internal Server Error response) because the unanchored `RewriteRule` *pattern* also matches the *substitution* string (a root-relative URL-path) and so the rewritten URL-path is rewritten again and again...

In a *server* context, you could write it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/files/(.+\.txt)$ /var/www/html/files/$1 [L]
```

(If you are not expecting subdirectories of the `/files` directory then the regex should be made more restrictive, eg. `([^/]+\.txt)`)